# Finding parameters to inform ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, parameter-estimation

In my model I have the interaction between parasite and immune repsonse and I want to find a value for the model parameter of death rate of parasite due to immune system killing.

The form of my equation is
${dP \over dt}=- {d P I \over kP+I}$,
P is the parasite and I is the immune cells where $d$ is the death rate ( which I am trying to find) and k is the ratio dependent constant as in [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.9798&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Form literature I found a figure that measures the death of parasite over time, which is given as the **percentage** of parasite that is killed.
  [image]

1)By fitting a function of the form $1-e^{-dt}$  would I be able to estimate `d` and does this match with my ODE equation?
Is there any other function or method that I can use to find `d`?

2) Or because this figure looks exponential, by converting it into logarithmic scale, can I directly read off the slope and obtain `d`?

3)As in the model I have the parasite and immune cells in **numbers**, does it matter I am using values from a **percentage** figure? I am not good with percentages and so I would like to know if I have to convert these percentages to numbers before I can use data on this figure.

Comment: What do you know about $I$? Does it depend on $t$?

Comment: @user121049 I have set $I$ to be generated proportional to `P` and so it varies over time